# Tree data structure in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, expression-trees

I need to implement a Tree data structure in Objective C and figure out how it works.

So what I know right now:

**About - how it looks.**

Tree is a recursive data structure. There are few parameters that I have to to implement, for example without methods for add, search, delete and other:

```
id info;
id left_node;
id right_node;
```

As I understand info - is a value that each node stores (e.g. NSInteger, NSString or something else). left_node and right_node there are pointers to other nodes in current tree or subtree.

**About add to tree**

For example I need to add next data that based on expression below:

**50*(10-(5+6)) + (60*(10-2))**

So on this step I have a problem, because I don't now how it will looks in tree and I need help with this.

Comment: `NSInteger` is not a class, it can't be stored in an `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v googled for you:

[image]

this is `(4*3)+((2*7)-5)`

so `info` must be a class that is something like

```
bool isOperation;
NSInteger number;
NSInteger operation idx;   //like 0 for '+', 1 for '-' ecc. to evaluate in a case
```